# PhpStorm: Failed to parse validation script output PHP version not installed Debugger not Installed

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm on Windows 10 x64 and today I wanted to install a new version of XAMPP. What I did was to uninstall my current one and then remove PHP from the environment variables. After that, I downloaded XAMPP as usual and installed it along with Xdebug, the same way that has worked for me during the past two years.

When I opened PhpStorm and went to set the CLI interpreter I noticed that it said "PHP version: Not installed" and "Debugger: Not installed" (although I have the PHP executable set to C:\xampp\php\php.exe).

What I did after that was to try reinstalling PhpStorm, both with my current settings and then other settings. It didn't help.

Upon checking the PHP version in the command line it does say that I have the new version installed. I am also able to do a simple echo 'hello'; and have it printed in the browser on my localhost. I'm not sure what to make of that. However, debugging inside PhpStorm does not work despite seeing on my PHPinfo that Xdebug is installed.

After googling around I don't see much that is relevant to what I'm doing. It seems like everyone who faces this issue is using a remote interpreter and a mac.

Does someone know what to do about it with my settings or have any suggestions on how to get this solved?

Setup:

- Windows 10 Version 1903 for 64
- xampp-windows-x64-7.4.1-0-VC15-installer
- PhpStorm 2019.3.1
- PHP 7.4.1
- Zend Engine v3.4.0, with Xdebug v2.9.0

Error message:
Failed to parse validation script output

Comment: Probably, XAMPP is using two different .ini files for the web mode and for the CLI mode (the PHP interpreter in PhpStorm is designed to run CLI scripts).
I suppose that `C:\xampp\php\php.exe --version` would not show you any sign of Xdebug being installed, right? If so, please check what .ini file it's using with `C:\xampp\php\php.exe --ini` and add Xdebug to it.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov It does though.
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 17 2019 19:24:02) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2017 x64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans

Comment: I missed the fact that the version also can't be checked. Add `#com.jetbrains.php` to Help | Debug Log Settings, restart the IDE, click refresh in the interpreter settings and then share the IDE log

Answer (score 3):

In my case Comodo Internet Security (CIS) was adding php.exe to blocked applications.

Unblocking it fixed the issue.

My config:

- PHP 7.4.5 64 NTS
- Windows 10 1909
- PhpStorm 2020.1

Comment: was facing same issue. solved by adding php.exe in the list of allowed apps in windows firewall.